# re-arranging a collection list based on another collection

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following query

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ 
$start n=node(*) match p=n-[r:LIKES]->items return n,collect(r.w),collect(items.name);
==> +------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
==> | n                    | collect(r.w)           | collect(items.name)   |
==> +------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
==> | Node[249]{name:"u1"} | [0,0.93]               | ["f5","f2"]           |
==> | Node[248]{name:"u2"} | [0,-0.76,1,-0.66]      | ["f4","f3","f2","f1"] |
==> +------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I want to re-order the items according to sorted values of r.w like the following

```
==> +------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
==> | n                    | collect(r.w)           | collect(items.name)   |
==> +------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
==> | Node[249]{name:"u1"} | [0.93,0]             | ["f2","f5"]           |
==> | Node[248]{name:"u2"} | [1,0,-0.66,-0.76]    | ["f2","f4","f1","f3"] |
==> +------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

How can I re-arrange elements of   collect(items.name) according to sorted values of collect(r.w)?

Comment: This may help. http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-with.html#with-sort-results-before-using-collect-on-them

Comment: Thanks but I need to reorder the items collection according to the sorted values of r.w collection, I don;t know how to do it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it may be like this

```
START n=node(*) 
MATCH p=n-[r:LIKES]->items
WITH n,r,items
ORDER BY r.w DESC, items.name DESC
RETURN n,collect(r.w),collect(items.name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Pipe your results through `WITH` and then order them. Then do the aggregation via `RETURN` as normal.

```
START n=node(*) 
MATCH p=n-[r:LIKES]->items
WITH n,r,items
ORDER BY r.w DESC
RETURN n,collect(r.w),collect(items.name);
```

Comment: I already tried it, it just reorders the r.w, does not affect the ordering of items.name. I don;t know how to link the two collections together